# Passing command line arguments to different class

Tags: java

I'm providing command line arguments to a java application with two classes. The arguments used by methods in the class containing main() work fine, but the other arguments give me 'can't find symbol' errors. I think I am just providing args in the wrong place but I can't seem to get the right one.

Here is a snippet of the code in the class causing the issue:

```
public abstract class Sample { 

public Sample() throws Exception {
        initialise(args);
}

public void initialise() {
        //do something
}
}
```

and i'm trying use the args in this method:

```
private SampleIF getPrincipal() {
        SampleIF xyz = auth(args[0], args[1]);
}
```

The auth() method looks similar to this:

```
protected SampleIF auth(String user, String pass) {
        //do something
}
```

Comment: Your initialize method doesn't have any parameters. You need to change it to ``public void initialize(String a, String b)``

Comment: `args` isn't some special item in java. The main method receives an array of String as an argument to the method. You need to make that available to your class some way, such as suggested passing it as an argument. Or make a static field.

Answer (score 2):

I see nowhere in your `Sample` class where it's accepting args to pass around. It should be like

```java
public class Sample {
    public Sample(String[] args) {
        initialize(args);
    }
    public void initialize(String[] args) {
        // Do something
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample s = new Sample(args);
    }
}
```